# mysql query does not reflect complete result

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to run following query:

```
SELECT * FROM cdr 
    WHERE clid REGEXP '^[\d\" <> 0-9]+$' 
        AND duration > '00:00:00' 
        AND dst BETWEEN '1234' AND '1300' 
    ORDER BY calldate DESC 
    LIMIT 5
```

The problem I am facing is that I still see results that are equal to duration 00:00:00. However if I remove `AND dst BETWEEN '1234' AND '1300'` and run the same query then I get desired results with values greater then duration 00:00:00.

I want duration values greater then 00:00:00 but between dst 1234 and 1300. What am I doing wrong? :( Someone please help me, thanks!

Comment: This looks like a asterisk database.

Comment: can you post some relevant data?

Comment: Try to use CAST('00:00:00' AS time) instead of '00:00:00'

Comment: yes its asterisk database

Comment: What is the data type of `dst` and `duration`?

Comment: post some DATA!! can't help you without it :)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! All of you asking me for data, actually made me look into the data, since I was running this query from PHP. I then looked and ran the query directly into mysql and noticed that it was reflecting right data as duration was always greater then '00:00:00'. I adjust my query to following, to solve my problem. 

SELECT * FROM cdr WHERE clid REGEXP '^[\d\" <> 0-9]+$' AND disposition = 'Answered' AND dst BETWEEN '1234' AND '1300' ORDER BY calldate DESC LIMIT 5

Thanks once again guys. What would world be like if there weren't people to help each other. :)